# How to optimize the occupied memory using Ruby with Gitlab

Tags: ruby, git, gitlab

run: top

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
13960 git       20   0 2032080 336220  13304 S   1.0 16.3   0:31.50 ruby                                
14284 git       20   0  554792 300168  10844 S   0.0 14.5   0:04.27 ruby                                
14287 git       20   0  546056 291068  10652 S   0.0 14.1   0:03.13 ruby                                
 2705 mysql     20   0 1082876 287544    380 S   0.0 13.9   0:01.70 mysqld                              
14104 git       20   0  524072 276016  13324 S   0.0 13.4   0:24.69 ruby                                
14281 git       20   0  524072 267504   4812 S   0.0 13.0   0:00.00 ruby                                                         
13978 gitlab-+  20   0  579824  39872  39280 S   0.0  1.9   0:00.12 postgres                            
 1404 www       20   0  142196  31304    820 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.05 nginx                               
 1405 www       20   0  142196  31304    820 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.05 nginx                               
 1403 www       20   0  142196  30992    508 S   0.0  1.5   0:00.04 nginx
```

My machine only has 2GB of memory.

Is there a way to optimize the configuration and reduce the memory consumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really: see [GitLab Requirements for memory](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html#memory)

> You need at least 8GB of addressable memory (RAM + swap) to install and use GitLab!
>
> The operating system and any other running applications will also be using memory so **keep in mind that you need at least 4GB available before running GitLab**. With less memory GitLab will give strange errors during the reconfigure run and 500 errors during usage.
>
> We recommend having at least [2GB of swap on your server](https://askubuntu.com/a/505344/5470), even if you currently have enough available RAM. Having swap will help reduce the chance of errors occurring if your available memory changes.
> We also recommend [configuring the kernel’s swappiness setting](https://askubuntu.com/a/103916/5470) to a low value like 10 to make the most of your RAM while still having the swap available when needed.